# Infinite amount of subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Suppose I have a sequence that seems random, increases and diverges to infinity:

$A_{n}=\left\{2,5,9,12,15,17,23,25,29,33,34...A_{\infty}\right\}$

Now I want to remove all of the positions in this sequence that equal to the numbers that are not in the sequence like: Remove $2$ (1st position), remove $9$ (3rd position), remove $12$ (4th position) to get:

$B_{n}=\left\{5,15,29...B_{\infty}\right\}$

How would I describe or denote this process, if I were to keep repeating it off to infinity to get more and more subsequences?

Comment: The subsequence $B_n$ is just $B_n=A_{A_n}$. E.g., $B_1=A_{A_1}=A_2=5$, $B_2=A_{A_2}=A_{5}=15$, and so on. If you wanted to repeat the same process with the $B_n$ sequence, you could define $C_n=B_{B_n}=B_{A_{A_n}}=A_{A_{A_{A_n}}}$.